# Unable to change module directory "No Module named 'X' " Python, Django

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a "forum" app, and i'm moving my project directory from:

```
rusc
  |-LinkMeta
  |-cela
  |-tag
  |-faq
  |-post
  |-resource
  |-rusc
```

**To:**

```
rusc
 |-LinkMeta
 |-rusc
    |-cela
    |-tag
    |-faq
    |-post
    |-resource
```

I done for all of them except module Cela, when i try to move cela inside rusc gives me an error:(after changing the references to cela in the project)

```
Django Version:     1.8.6
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named 'cela'

Exception Location:     
                    C:\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py in        
import_module, line 126
Python Executable:  C:\Python35\python.exe
Python Version:     3.5.0
Python Path:    

['C:/Users/zartch/PycharmProjects/Django/rusc',
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 4.0.5\\helpers\\pydev',
'C:\\Users\\zartch\\PycharmProjects\\Django\\rusc',
'C:\\Python35\\python35.zip',
'C:\\Python35\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python35\\lib',
'C:\\Python35',
'C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages']


Installed Applications:
(
 ...More apps heare...
 'rusc.post',
 'rusc.etiqueta',
 'rusc.recurs',
 'rusc.usuari',
 'rusc.cela',
 'rusc.faq',
 'rusc.cela.moderaciomodels')

Traceback:
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:/Users/zartch/PycharmProjects/Django/rusc\rusc\cela\views.py" in ruscView
  23.     return render(request, "rusc.html", {'celas':celas,'notifications': notif})
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  99.         return template.render(context, request)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  209.                 with context.bind_template(self):
File "C:\Python35\lib\contextlib.py" in __enter__
  59.             return next(self.gen)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py" in bind_template
  237.         processors = (template.engine.template_context_processors +
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in __get__
  59.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in template_context_processors
  90.         return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in <genexpr>
  90.         return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py" in import_string
  26.     module = import_module(module_path)
File "C:\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  126.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

Exception Type: ImportError at /rusc/
Exception Value: No module named 'cela'
```

It blames on ...\rusc\cela\views.py

```
from rusc.cela.forms import celaForm
from rusc.cela.models import get_cela, Cela
from rusc.post.models import Post,folksonomia

  def ruscView(request):

    celas = Cela.objects.exclude(tipus='X')
    notif=[]

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        notif = request.user.notifications.unread()

    return render(request, "rusc.html", {'celas':celas,'notifications': notif})
```

if i return cela to the top level it just works ok.
Any suggestions wood be appreciated.

**Debugging def ruscView(request):**

```
def ruscView(request):
   celas = Cela.objects.exclude(tipus='X')
   #The celas object is created [<Cela: Pruebas>]


   notif=[]
   if request.user.is_authenticated():
       notif = request.user.notifications.unread()
   #No user, notif = [], skip if

   return render(request, "rusc.html", {'celas':celas,'notifications': notif})
#This goes to shorcuts.py render, heare :
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
    (returns: No module named 'cela') 
    #Continues on loader.py line 66 method render_to_string
      #Who calls template = get_template(template_name, using=using) (loader.py line 29, with args('rusc.html', _dirs_undefined, None))
      #get_template calls engines wich returns a list with the correct folder of the template ('C:/Users/zartch/PycharmProjects/Django/rusc\\rusc\\cela\\templates') and returns correctly the template
      #returns to render_to_string and template.render(context, request) i wich is returning the error : "No module named 'cela'"
        #in django.py def render is giving the error when calls "self.template.render(context)"
          # in template\base.py the method render give me the HTML of the page who has to be displayed
          #This returns to render and give me {NoReverseMatch}Reverse for 'rusc.cela' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
      #Returns to render to string returning ({ImportError}No module named 'cela')
    #Then go to base.py get_response and because response= None rise the exception
```

Comment: is there an \__init__.py file in the rusc folder?

Comment: Yes an empty _ _init_ _.py , there are modules working inside rusc folder

Comment: Maybe it should be `from rusc.rusc import cela` ?

Comment: `No module named 'rusc.rusc'` , but is strange, with rusc.post.models and rusc.faq.models and the others works ok.
Also, Pycharm finds the module.

Comment: How about `from cela.forms import celaForm` :-)

Comment: `No module named 'cela'`. Anyways `from cela.models import Cela` is the right import in the top directory.
I know the import must be `from rusc.cela.models import  Cela` because Pycharm is detecting it, and the other modules works and are in the same route.

Comment: It looks like it's the `return render(request, "rusc.html", ...)`  that is causing the error, right?

Comment: Did you have the right values (folders) in the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in your settings.py file?

Comment: My template dirs: `'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates').replace('\\','/'),],`

I just updated the question with some new debug information inside django framework